# Iterating through dictionary with nested lists and printing at board position

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-lists, python-3.6

I have a dictionary with strings as keys and a list with coordinates of points as values.

i.e.

```
    dict = {'.' : [[0,0],[0,1]...],  'X': [[0,2], [8,1]...] }
```

where the 'X' and '.' keys don't contain the same coordinates.

My problem is iterating through them and printing the key at the location of the values. I tried a nested for loop but I don't know how to access coordinates on an output terminal.

I want to print my output to console not plot it.

I want my output to look similar to:

```
..................X....
XX...........X.........
XXX....................
XXX....X...X...X..X....
.......................
.......................
.......................
```

I am using python 3

Comment: You want to plot or just print the key/values pair?

Comment: You've given sample input (or, partial at least), now give sample output and add your attempts so far.

Comment: The way I read this is that you want to iterate through all the coordinates (two integer ranges -- for example 0-8 inclusive -- and for each coordinate pair, perform a "reverse lookup" to find the key that contains that coordinate pair, and print it?

Comment: It appears to me that you should rather use the coords as the keys and the symbols as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a 2d list that represents your board

```
board = [[' ' for _ in range(9)] for _ in range(9)]
```

You can display it with `pprint` for example

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(board)

[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

So to perform your substitutions, you can loop through your dictionary and replace those elements as needed

```
d = {'.' : [[0,0],[0,1]],  'X': [[0,2], [8,1]] }
for k, v in d.items():
    for i, j in v:
        board[i][j] = k
```

Which results in

```
>>> pprint.pprint(board)
[['.', '.', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to first "invert" the dictionary, then loop over your coordinates and look them up in the inverted dictionary.

Something like:

```
#d1 = {'.' : [[0,0],[0,1]...],  'X': [[0,2], [8,1]...] }
d1 = {'.' : [[0,0],[0,1]],  'X': [[0,2], [8,1]] }


# "Invert" the dictionary
d2 = {}
for (symbol, coords) in d1.items():
    for coord in coords:
        d2[tuple(coord)] = symbol           # Note 1  

# Display it (assuming your coordinates go from 0-9 inclusive
for y in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        sym = d2.get((x,y), ' ')            # Note 2
        print(sym, end='')                  # Note 2
    # Print a newline at the end of each row
    print()
```

Note 1: Here, `coord` is a 2-element list, but as lists cannot be used as dictionary keys, I convert them to tuples.

Note 2: This is only necessary because the example code has an incomplete `d1` dictionary.  If your `d1` dictionary has all the pairs accounted for, you could combine these two lines into simply

```
print(d2[(x,y)], end='')
```

Note 3: Here we're specifying an optional argument to the `print` function, telling it *not* to add a newline after printing.

The output looks a little weird:

```
.         
.       X 
X
```

(with additional space-only lines) but only because my `d1` dictionary is incomplete.

Lastly, you may go through all of this and notice that your board seems off, like the pattern is going up when it should be pointing right.  If that's the case, your coordinates are in (y,x) order and I assumed they were in (x,y) order.  Just change the line

```
d2.get((x,y), ' ')
```

to

```
d2.get((y,x), ' ')
```

or, if you made the simplification in Note 2, change

```
print(d2[(x,y)], end='')
```

to

```
print(d2[(y,x)], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize an empty board populated with dots, this can be done with:

```
board = [['.' for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
```

which gives an output of:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

However, this is not a neat way of printing the board so before going further, we can create a way of printing it.

This can be done by looping through the `rows` and for each `row` joining that list to create a string and printing it like so:

```
for r in board:
   print(''.join(r))
```

this little for loops neatly prints the current board as:

```
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
........
```

to replace the dots with crosses where specified in the `dict`, we can really simply do (this assumes the coordinates are of form `[x, y]`):

```
d = {'.' : [[0,0],[0,1]],  'X': [[0,2], [4,1], [2,5]] }
for c in d['X']:
   board[c[1]][c[0]] = 'X'
```

we can then display the board as before and we get:

```
........
....X...
X.......
........
........
..X.....
........
........
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just store the coords as the keys not the values, unless you have a special reason to do that. Of course you can't use lists as keys so you have to use tuples instead.

```
board = {(x, y): '.' for x in range(10) for y in range(10)}

board[(2, 3)] = 'X'

for y in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        print(board[(x, y)], end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . X . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . .
```